# url shortening for SEO with PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code for shortening URL for SEO .

```
<?php
function getURL($url){

    $urlGet = parse_url($url);
    $queries = explode("&", $urlGet['query']);
    $newURL = $urlGet['path'];
    foreach($queries as $query) {
        $queryContent = explode("=", $query);
        $queryContent[0] == "Ad"? $newURL .= str_replace(" ", "-", $queryContent[1]):$newURL .= "/".$query;

    }
    return $newURL;
    }

    ?>
```

When i click the link below im getting this error
Not Found

The requested URL /deffsale/AllAds/Other-Mobile-Phones/Tablets was not found on this server.

```
<a href="<?php echo getURL('AllAds/?Ad=Other Mobile Phones/Tablets'); ?>">Other Mobile Phones/Tablets</a><br>
```

However, on clicking the intial link before shortening the url, it's functioning very well.Im testing it on my localhost.Please help me solve this problem

```
<a href="AllAds/?Ad=Other Mobile Phones/Tablets">Other Mobile Phones/Tablets</a><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Links point to locations, you can't just change a link up and expect your server to magically find it just because it looks kind of similar. You need to tell your server how to handle the "seo url", which is most commonly done via apache mod_rewrite.

Comment: Im really in darkness illustrate further